# Inject service with Dagger and Robolectric

Tags: android, dependency-injection, robolectric, dagger

I'm trying to inject the service `TelephonyManager` with Dagger. I'm following this [sample](https://github.com/christopherperry/dagger/tree/master/examples/android). I extended the `Application` class to create the graph and defined an `ApplicationModule` where `ServiceModule` is included and other modules will be included in the future.

**Edit:**

Now the system service is injected on an `Activity` without any problems. I was missing `FinderApplication.inject(this)` inside the `Activity`. It has an injection but still doesn't inject under testing with `Robolectric`. I added the test case at the bottom of this post:

**Edit-2:**
`ApplicationModule` deleted and created `BaseActivity` with:

```
((FinderApplication) getApplication()).getGraph().inject(this);
```

on `onCreate` method. The error I'm getting is:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: ServiceModule.()

But if I define an empty constructor I get a null pointer when the injected class is needed.

**FinderApplication.java**

```
public class FinderApplication extends Application {
    private ObjectGraph mObjectGraph;

    @Override
    public final void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mObjectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new ServiceModule(this));
    }

    public final ObjectGraph getGraph() {
        return mObjectGraph;
    }
}
```

**ServiceModule.java**

```
@Module(entryPoints = { SimCardActivity.class, SimService.class })
public class ServiceModule {

    private Context mContext;

    public ServiceModule(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Provides @Singleton
    TelephonyManager provideTelephonyManager(){
        return (TelephonyManager) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    }
}
```

**SimCardActivityTest.java**

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class SimCardActivityTest { 

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        ObjectGraph.create(new TestModule()).inject(this);;
    }

    @Module(
            includes = ServiceModule.class,
            overrides = true,
            entryPoints = {SimCardActivityTest.class, SimCardActivity.class}
    )
    static class TestModule{
        public static TelephonyManager TELEPHONY_MANAGER = 
            Mockito.mock(TelephonyManager.class);

        @Provides @Singleton
        TelephonyManager provideTelephonyManager(){
            return TELEPHONY_MANAGER;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the includes flag in the @Module annotation will provide members for other modules. "includes" is for using another module to make sure all of the injectable members in each entry point is satisfied, so that the module creates a complete object graph.

Comment: It's seems like includes flag really includes the specified modules. Because is injecting when the app is running normally.

Comment: You're injecting the test case into the object graph instead of the activity, perhaps?

Comment: This doesn't explain the error you're seeing, but I don't think the object graph created in your setUp method is actually being used for anything.  You use it to call inject(this), but SimCardActivityTest has no dependencies, so you're not injecting anything there.  I think you need a setObjectGraph method on FinderApplication, and then you need to call that from setUp.

Comment: @AndyDennie You're right, I think they are two totally different graphs. What I need to do is to inject a mock object inside SimCardActivity.

Comment: BTW, I figured out the NoSuchMethodException problem (having just run into it myself).  Dagger's ReflectiveModuleAdapter can't instantiate an included module unless that included module has a no-arg constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @AndyDennie said on his comment I was doing no injection in the test class. Injecting the activity under test instead of creating it on `setUp()` solved the problem.

My current test case (relevant code) looks like this:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class SimCardActivityTest {

    @Inject
    private SimCardActivity mActivity;

    private TelephonyManager mTelephonyManager;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        ObjectGraph.create(new ServiceModule(Robolectric.application), 
                           new ServiceTestModule()).inject(this);
    }

    @Module(
            includes = {ServiceModule.class },
            overrides = true,
            entryPoints = {SimCardActivity.class, SimCardActivityTest.class}
    )
    static class ServiceTestModule {
        public static TelephonyManager TELEPHONY_MANAGER = 
            Mockito.mock(TelephonyManager.class);

        @Provides
        @Singleton
        TelephonyManager provideTelephonyManager(){
            return TELEPHONY_MANAGER;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Minor comment: I believe that if you provide the TelephonyManager with @Singleton, you don't need to declare an static instance (TELEPHONY_MANAGER) and return it. You could directy return Mockito.mock(TelephonyManager.class), in the provides method, as it will be executed only once.